# How to call oracle parameterized function using entity framework core?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a function in the oracle database with a signature similar to **Function test_fun(id IN NUMBER) RETURN result_out;** where result_out is of type REF CURSOR.
I am sure there is no error in oracle function as it is being called in another application using ADO.Net(oracle.manageddataaccess).

Even I dont get any exception when the function is called, I am just not getting anything as output in the return Value parameter.

can anyone help with call this function using entity framework core(using version 5).

```
string sql = "BEGIN :result_out := test_fun(:id) END;";
var parms = new OracleParameter[]
{
     new OracleParameter
     {
       ParameterName = "id",
       Value = 10,
       OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int32
     },
     new OracleParameter
     {  
       ParameterName = "result_out",
       OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor,
       Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
     }
};
var x = _conext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql,parms);
var result = parms[1].Value;
```

Comment: How about using `ParameterDirection.Output` instead?

Comment: @IvanStoev I tried that also, it didnt work as there is no output parameter in function just a return value of ref cursor

Comment: Hmm, I have no Oracle environment to test right now. But have some memories that it binds parameters by position by default, and it cannot be controlled when using EF Core methods. Did you try swapping the parameters in the array?

Comment: I tried passing parameters individually.
example : _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(inParm,outParm);
Still no luck

Comment: I meant the out parameter to be the *first*, since it is appearing first in the SQL block. e.g. `ExecuteSqlRaw("BEGIN :0 := test_fun(:1) END;", outParam, inParam);`